# How to get user page in passport

Tags: node.js, logging, passport.js

I am making very simple user login system. Every users have their own page (username.html) . Once users login in a system they should get own pages.   Here I used [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) and  my code is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
            // request and response objects
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // not authenticated then redirect to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
}

router.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('login', {failureRedirect: '/'}),
         function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.

         res.redirect(req.user.username);
         });

/*  GET user Page  */

    router.get('/user.username', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

        res.render('user.username', { user: req.user });
```

I stuck in getting user page. Do you have any suggestion how I can get '/user.username' page in `router.get`?. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in the way you are trying to pass parameters to the express get route.
The query parameters to be received must be specified after a `:`. For e.g.

```
app.get('/api/:version', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.version);
  });
```

This code snippet will recognize routes like `/api/1` , `/api/2` etc. Here `version` is the parameter to be received. The parameter's value can be accessed by using `req.param`.

So here, we need to redirect the user to his page after successful login.This can be done by creating a route as `"/:username"` which will accept `username` as a parameter and renders the user's page.

Now for e.g. if the user logs in as `'aarav'` then he will be redirected to `\aarav` which will be handled by the get route, thus rendering the appropriate page whose value is given by `req.params.username`.

Here goes the modified code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
            // request and response objects
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // not authenticated then redirect to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
}

router.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('login', {failureRedirect: '/'}),
         function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.

         res.redirect('/'+req.user.username);
         });

/*  GET user Page  */

    router.get('/:username', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

        res.render(req.params.username, { user: req.user });
```

Hope it helps :)